# Do function while key up in kendo mobile search box filterable

Tags: javascript, html, datasource, filtering, kendo-mobile

I need to be able to do an SQLite statement onShow of the kendo view which I have implemented fine. The first problem is, if the count comes back as more than 250, I dont want to show any data and if less or equal, then show data, here is what I have so far

```
 if(rs.rows.length > 250 || rs.rows.length == 0)
        {
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data:viewModel.resultsTest, group: "groupBy"});
        }
        else if(rs.rows.length <= 250)
        {
            $("#testList").data("kendoMobileListView").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({data:viewModel.resultsTest, group: "groupBy"}));
        }
```

As you can see, so far im not setting the listview datasource when there is a large amount of data, the problem is, i need that data source setting because it needs to filterable. But if I set the data source and set pageSize:0, it shows all of it.

The next issue is the large data being filterable. I want to be able to search that large data, and if the count of those search results is less than 250, then display the data.

***I have been playing around with idea of doing an sql statement whilst doing the "key up" event on the kendo filterable search box have no idea idea how to implement this, can someone please help me out?***

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Configure the datasource to use serverSide filtering and paging, which this you can limit the number of items to whatever you want.

var KendoDataSource_EmployeeAutoComplete = {
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    transport: {
        read: { url: '@Url.Action("GetAutoCompleteAsJson", "Employee")', dataType: "json" }
    }
};

See more details on the [help page from Kendo Datasource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-page).